# Eigen vector constructor initialization vs comma initialization

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, eigen

For Eigen vectors of a fixed size (eg `Eigen::Vector3d`, `Eigen::Vector4f`) there is the option to initialize the vector using the constructor as follows:

```
Eigen::Vector3d a(0.0, 1.0, 2.0);
```

However, Eigen also offers a way to use comma initialization of a general Eigen matrix that can be used in this case:

```
Eigen::Vector3d b;
b << 0.0, 1.0, 2.0;
```

Is one of the two methods preferable for speed or some other reasons? Or are they equal?

Comment: _or some other reasons_ I mean one of them is a single line of code and the other is two lines of code. IMO for that reason alone I'd use the former. The latter might allow you to be more easily switch types if you choose to do so. Take this all with a grain of salt though, I've never used `Eigen`, but `std::vector<int> a{0, 1, 2}` is better than the two line variant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage of the first version is that it will fail at compile time if you pass the wrong number of arguments, e.g. because you misstyped Vector2d as Vector3d.

Performance-wise, the compiler is able to optimize both the same. Checked it with GCC.